# Using sed command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

This is my simple shell script

sample.sh

```
LOCALCONFIGDIR="Install"
CONFLOC="$LOCALCONFIGDIR/server.conf"
echo "Enter Web Url:"
read  weburl
echo "sed 's/^\(ServerName\)$/\1 "$weburl"/' "$CONFLOC
sed "'s/^\(ServerName\)$/\1 "$weburl"/' "$CONFLOC
```

When I run this code, I get the result in echo command as following.

```
sed 's/^\(ServerName\)$/\1 www.weburl.com/' Install/server.conf
```

But when executing sed command in the next line, It says the below error.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

I tried the command produced in echo statement from Terminal screen, It is working. But `Line number 5`, doesn't working from shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one set of quotes, not two, and since you want the `$weburl` variable expanded, you need to use double quotes:

```
sed "s/^\(ServerName\)$/\1 $weburl/" "$CONFLOC"
```

That'll be OK as long as `$weburl` doesn't contain any slashes.  If it does, you need to use a different character than `/`, such as `%`, to separate the parts of the substitute command:

```
sed "s%^\(ServerName\)$%\1 $weburl%" "$CONFLOC"
```

Comment: It works. sed "s%$^\(ServerName\)$%\1 www.weburl.com%" Install/server.conf . But It doesn't add the text www.weburl.com after the ServerName.

Comment: I just removed a stray `$` in the second `sed`; if you'd used that, it would have stopped the match working.  If that isn't the problem, then maybe your configuration file has spaces before or after `ServerName` on the configuration line, or maybe the file doesn't have a line containing just `ServerName`.

Comment: Perhaps sed commands are best served by using single quotes and exposing the double quoted shell variables i.e. `sed 's/.../'"${var}"'/' file`. The reason being that meta-characters unwittingly used in the sed command(s) my be interpolated by the shell.

Comment: @potong: What you wrote is what I'd usually do, but it isn't crucial this time.